# Excel Formula to get Accounting Day like Day 0, Day 1, Day 2 till Day 5 Excluding Weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
Date        Status          LastWorkingDate
7/3/2017    Day 0           7/3/2017
7/1/2017    Day 1           7/3/2017
7/2/2017    Day 1           7/3/2017
6/30/2017   Day 1           7/3/2017
6/29/2017   Day 2           7/3/2017
6/28/2017   Day 3           7/3/2017
6/27/2017   Day 4           7/3/2017
6/26/2017   Day 5           7/3/2017
6/25/2017   Day 6           7/3/2017
6/24/2017   Day 6           7/3/2017
6/23/2017   Day 6           7/3/2017
6/22/2017   More than Day 6 7/3/2017
7/4/2017    Day 0           7/4/2017
7/3/2017    Day 1           7/4/2017
7/2/2017    Day 2           7/4/2017
7/1/2017    Day 2           7/4/2017
6/30/2017   Day 2           7/4/2017
6/29/2017   Day 3           7/4/2017
6/28/2017   Day 4           7/4/2017
6/27/2017   Day 5           7/4/2017
6/26/2017   Day 6           7/4/2017
6/25/2017   More than Day 6 7/4/2017
```

i have tried using =
`IF(NETWORKDAYS(E21,G21)-1=0,"day 0",IF(NETWORKDAYS(E21,G21)-1=1,"Day 1",IF(NETWORKDAYS(E21,G21)-1=2,"Day 2",IF(NETWORKDAYS(E21,G21)-1=3,"Day 3",IF(NETWORKDAYS(E21,G21)-1=4,"Day 4",IF(NETWORKDAYS(E21,G21)-1=5,"Day 5","Greater than 5 Days"))))))` 
but not getting desired output.

All i want is Day 0 to Day 5 based on two date columns(Date and LAstWorkingDate).

1. Day 0  = if today is monday then lastworkingdate will be friday and friday, Sat and Sunday will become Day 0 and previous week's thursday will be Day 1 and so on
2. Day 1 = if today is Tuesday then Lastworking Date will be Monday and Monday will become Day 0, Friday,Sat and Sunday will be Day 1 and so on
3. Day 2 = if today is wednesday ten Lastworkind Date will be Tuesday and Tuesday will become Day 0, Monday - Day 1, Friday, Sat and Sunday wull be Day 2 and so on
   .
   .
   .

Comment: What is the logic behind the `Day 1`, `Day 2`... ?

Comment: @A.S.H  check the subject line, it means Status has to be retreived using formula considering Date and Lastworkking Date Column.

Comment: @NiteshHalai Day 0 is if both columns (Date and last working Day are equal) Day 1 is when Date column is one day prior to Last working Date column.  DONOT CONSIDER WEEKENDS AS THEY WILL BECOME 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 based on last working day

Comment: @baimzz edit your question in comprehensible way

Comment: Still unclear. Please tell us 1. The exact problem, 2. What have you tried so far, 3. Where did you get stuck, 4. What is the desired behavior.

Comment: updated the question as per your comments

Comment: Do you need a VBA solution, or will any formula just do?

Comment: I can interprete your code as such a desired output is a difference between two edges only when it is less than or equal = 5, but the last note is vague to me

Comment: any thing is fine for me as long as i am getting right output..

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`="Day "&(NETWORKDAYS(IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=7,A1-2,IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=6,A1-1,A1)),C1)-1)`

Using your current layout for Last Working Day and Date.
The weekday functions are needed because otherwise the Saturday and Sunday would get the same value as Monday instead of Friday.

Of course you can wrap the whole thing in an `IF`-formula to make sure you display "Greater than 5 days" when the value is bigger than 5.

Output:

```
Date     | Formula column | Last working day
--------------------------------------------
6/17/2017| Day 11         | 7/3/2017  'Weekend
6/18/2017| Day 11         | 7/3/2017  'Weekend
6/19/2017| Day 10         | 7/3/2017
6/20/2017| Day 9          | 7/3/2017
6/21/2017| Day 8          | 7/3/2017
6/22/2017| Day 7          | 7/3/2017
6/23/2017| Day 6          | 7/3/2017
6/24/2017| Day 6          | 7/3/2017  'Weekend
6/25/2017| Day 6          | 7/3/2017  'Weekend
6/26/2017| Day 5          | 7/3/2017
6/27/2017| Day 4          | 7/3/2017
6/28/2017| Day 3          | 7/3/2017
6/29/2017| Day 2          | 7/3/2017
6/30/2017| Day 1          | 7/3/2017
7/1/2017 | Day 1          | 7/3/2017  'Weekend
7/2/2017 | Day 1          | 7/3/2017  'Weekend
7/3/2017 | Day 0          | 7/3/2017
```